# NSManaged Versus the ! operator

Tags: ios, swift

So I've read a lot about @NSManaged and a lot of people are saying it's the same as the @dynamic property in Objective-C. Someone also said that it was basically that the machine code needs to be present at compile-time for normal code, but with the NSManaged tag you can pinky promise the compiler that you'll put it there just before.

Now what's the difference between NSManaged and the ! operator? To my eye they both seem very similar in the sense that I am telling the compiler that they will be set at runtime even if my code doesn't reflect that.

Some clarification would be nice just to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `@NSManaged` and the `!` operator is that the former tells the compiler that **Core-Data** will take care of the variable/constant's implementation whereas the `!` operator just unwraps optional values allowing you to not have to set an original value when you declare a variable/constant. A variable or constant declared like so: `var/let value: CGFLoat!` is an **implicitly unwrapped** optional, meaning that you do not have to unwrap it to use it. HOWEVER, it can still be nil and if you try to use it when it is nil Xcode will yell at you at runtime (the app will crash).

Comment: "if you try to use it when it is nil the compiler will complain." Nope, the compiler will let you do it and say "Welp, you're on your own now". If a nil is encountered at **runtime**, it'll crash.

Comment: @AMomchilov, you're absolutely right. I corrected it accordingly so others do not get confused.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Okay so I have a quick followup. So I was animating a progress indicator and the animating angle I was using was initially `var angle: Double!`, and it did not animate at all. The progress indicator was not even changing to the final value. However, when I changed it to `@NSManaged var angle: Double`, it worked beautifully. Is this because now CoreData was used to update the variable and thus it would run the `drawInContext` function every time it was updated?

Comment: @A.Ayyakad , many things could cause this to happen. You should probably post it in another question as it is off-topic from this one and comments generally should not be used to discuss new issues. Also, in your question consider adding before/after code so that others and I can try to answer your question.

Comment: @ike10 Thanks I actually figured it out but I'll keep that in mind for the future!